# How to make a string into a list with only first part of the string

Tags: python, list

say that i have a string with e.g first name surname

```
string = "Jessica Tree, Jefferson True, Mike Will"
```

how do i make a list taking only first or last name?

```
final = ["Jessica", "Jefferson", "Mike"]
```

or

```
final = ["Tree", "True", "Will"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` to split a string on a character, which gives you a list of all the whole names. Then you loop through the names, remove the whitespace before and after the whole name with `strip`, use `split` again but now on the whitespace in the whole name and use either the first (index 0) or last (index 1) name:

```
name_type = 0 # =0 for first name, =1 for last name 

string = "Jessica Tree, Jefferson True, Mike Will"

final = [name.strip().split(" ")[name_type] for name in string.split(",")]
print(final)
```

Out:

```
['Jessica', 'Jefferson', 'Mike']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split()`.

```
string = "Jessica Tree, Jefferson True, Mike Will"
final = [name.strip().split(" ")[0] for name in string.split(",")]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name_string = "Jessica Tree, Jefferson True, Mike Will"
full_name_list = name_string.split(",")
new_list = []
for name in full_name_list:
    new_list.append(name.split()[0])
```